# Power Query/Power BI Match Pattern Fix Suite # in Address

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have data where there's an address with Suite #.  What I need to do is be able to split out those where the Suite # and Ste don't have space and then find and replace them.  I've tried many different filtering but will also filter where the pattern is similar.  What type of regular expression function can I use to find these and then add the space if applicable?

Data:

```
Ste 123
Ste1234
Ste3434
```

Comment: I would use a `.Replace` type function.  But regular expressions are not a part of Power Query.  Edit your question to show us what you have tried and where you have run into trouble.

Comment: "ste" is always a fixed value? or other value can be there before the suit number?

Answer (score 0):

If there is always value **Ste** in the beginning either with a space or no space, use of 2 replace in the string will give your expected output.

1. Replace " " (Space) with "" (no space) first.
2. Now replace "Ste" with "Ste "

Here below the code from **Advanced Editor**-

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"prev_step_name"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"your_column_name"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"prev_step_name","Ste","Ste ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"your_column_name"})
```

[image]